# How to get line no. after runing script which relassing lots of lines in putty

Tags: shell, runtime, stdout, stderr

First of all i m not very much of Unix guy...I have to get the no of lines processed after running one command which releasing 1000+ lines in putty screen. Once the command execution is completed, it should show me how many lines it throws and when it stops, i need to find the no. of lines in output.

I am trying below, but not getting success.

```
#! /bin/sh
enqueext -env EXR3 -P 4032 -type EnquedocExR3 -loglevel 9
RESULT=$?
echo $exectime - enqueued `expr $RESULT - 10` documents >> $logdir/$joblog
```

the above command `enqueext...` releases more than 1000 lines. once its stop, i need to find how many lines it released to capture the result.

I am trying to get no. of lines thru below expression.

```
RESULT=$?
```

But its giving me max 240 documents counts or less.

I need to capture total no. lines release by above command.

Comment: `$?` is the value returned by the most recent exiting (finishing) program. The convention is that `0`=success and any other number (up to 254) indicates an error. Numbers above 146(?) indicate the shell could not find the command to be executed.  ...

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish. I would, using a linux environment, run you command on the command-line (you can script it later), but save the output directly into a file, ie `enqueext -env EXR3 -P 4032 -type EnquedocExR3 -loglevel 9 > allenqueext_output.txt`. If you still see text on the screen, that text is being sent by the programs `Standard Error` stream. You can capture it separately by adding `2> /allenqueext_errors.txt` to the end of the above command. Now you can see how big each file is with `wc -l < *output.txt` Does that give you output that is usable?

Comment: Your terminology of "releasing lots of lines in putty screen", might be better stated as "the program prints all the lines of output to putty, but because of the putty's settings, only keeps the 1000 most recent". (You can change the size of your putty buffer in the settings). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by comments, it's not fully clear what is the real goal here. On surface, the output include log lines, so it's obvious why they need to be counted. Putting this issue on the side, one possible way to achieve the same is to use `tee` with process substitution to count the lines, while allowing the output to be displayed to the terminal.

```
#! /bin/bash
enqueext -env EXR3 -P 4032 -type EnquedocExR3 -loglevel 9 2>&1 | tee >(wc -l > linecount.txt)
RESULT=$(<linecount.txt)
echo $exectime - enqueued `expr $RESULT - 10` documents >> $logdir/$joblog
```

Notes:

1. Solution is using process substitution, which will require a shell that support it (bash, zsh, ...). Solution uses bash.
2. It is not clear if the output arrive on stdout, or stderr (given -logLevel). Assuming stderr.
3. Temporary file used to hold line count (linecount.txt) in the current directory. Can be modified to different location (e.g. /tmp/linecount.txt, ...)
4. Possible to use bash arithmetic $((...)) instead of `expr`